# Configuração .json

Tags: c, json, visual-studio-code

Estou tentando depurar meu código em C porém o console me retorna isso:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O meu launch.json está assim:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        // Use IntelliSense to find out which attributes exist for C# debugging
        // Use hover for the description of the existing attributes
        // For further information visit https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md
        "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "launch",
        "preLaunchTask": "build",
        // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/net6.0/ProgramaC.dll",
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        // For more information about the 'console' field, see https://aka.ms/VSCode-CS-LaunchJson-Console
        "console": "internalConsole",
        "stopAtEntry": false
    },
    {
        "name": ".NET Core Attach",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "attach"
    }
]
}
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: o erro é de arquivo inexistente. Tu checaste para ver se o caminho ali indicado existe?

Comment: Ss é o arquivo que está aberto no Vs Code